# How can the JQuery bind() plugin help me

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery
I am writing a simple data validation using JQuery.

Here is the HTML part:

```
<input type="text" id="testing">
```

This is the JQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#testing").click(function(){
     // doing something;
      });

$("#testing").change(function(){
      // doing something;
      });

$("#testing").mouseover(function(){
      // doing something;
      });
});
```

$("#testing") repeated three times in my sample code, is it possible to simplify this?
I am not sure if bind() can help solve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testing = $('#testing');
    testing.click(function() { });
    testing.change(function() { });
    testing.mouseover(function() { });
});
```

or (using chains):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* var testing = */ $('#testing') // the assignment is optional, but you can reuse the selector
        .click(function() { })
        .change(function() { })
        .mouseover(function() { });
});
```

with [`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) you can create eg. custom eventhandlers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testing = $('#testing');
    testing.bind('fill', function() { });
    testing.trigger('fill');
});
```

as reading through the docu, you could also do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* var testing = */ $('#testing') // the assignment is optional, but you can reuse the selector
        .bind('click change mouseover', function() { });
});
```

or with jquery 1.4:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* var testing = */ $('#testing') // the assignment is optional, but you can reuse the selector
        .bind({
                click: function() { },
                change: function() { },
                mouseover: function() { }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is chain-able. You can also do it like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#testing").click(function(){
     // doing somthing;
      }).change(function(){
      // doing somthing;
      }).mouseover(function(){
      // doing somthing;
      });
});
```

or with `.bind()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#testing").bind({
      click : function(){
      // doing somthing;
      },
      change : function(){
      // doing somthing;
      },
      mouseover : function(){
      // doing somthing;
      }    
  });
});
```

if you have just one action in all of that, you can do this,

```
$("#testing").bind('click change mouseover', function(){
     // doing same thing on three events
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set `var t = $("#testing");` just once at the start of the outer function (that identifies the node with that `id`), then call `t.click`, `t.change` and `t.mouseover`.

Answer (score 1):

#Testing shouldn't be repeated three times as # is an id.  You could use .Testing as the period signifies a class.

```
<input type="text" id="Testing" class="myTesting"/>
'.myTesting'
```

I actually prefer my code to look like yours as it's easier to ready.  Chaining can sometimes look and feel complex and if you miss a } or ) they can be difficult to track down.

But that is purely my opinion.

Comment: He's not repeating the element, just the query.
It's OK to use an Id, but chaining methods would have better performance:

    $("#testing").click(function(){ 
                   /* something */
                  }).change(function(){
                   /* something */
                  }).mouseover(function(){
                   /* something */
                  });

Comment: Wasn't sure about the performance actually.  Still if the performance hit is minimal i still prefer readability,

Comment: The performance hit is minimal in a normal page, but sometimes pages have hundreds or even thousands of elements and each query takes it's time.

Comment: `Chaining can sometimes look and feel complex and if you miss a } or ) they can be difficult to track down.` for me, it's not difficult. You just have to get used to it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

chaining methods would have better performance:

```
$("#testing").click(function(){ 
               /* something */
              }).change(function(){
               /* something */
              }).mouseover(function(){
               /* something */
              });
```

You can put the linebreaks wherever you want:

```
$("#testing").click(function(){ 
               /* something */
              })    // don't put a semicolon here

             .change(function(){
               /* something */
              })    // don't put a semicolon here either

             .mouseover(function(){
               /* something */
              });   // put it here because you will not continue chaining.
```

Bind provides extra functionality but it's not what you are asking for in this case.